# How to subtract each integer in an array from the previous integer and find the summation

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a numpy array that has the size (122,) and is made up of integers

I want to use the following formula:

[image]

I tried doing

```
value=sum((I[:-1]-I[1:])**2))
```

This line itself does not create an error, but whenever I try to use this value in the bigger formula it gives an invalid syntax error.

I want to use this value to plug into a bigger formula

[image]

I would like an answer of how to plug my array into this formula
For instance, the code for the second term in the bigger formula, I have written as follows:

```
calc = np.linalg.norm((RR_intervals[:-1])-(RR_intervals[1:]))                                                                     

p=(n-1)*sqrt(2)
o=(1/p)*calc
t=o**2
```

If I try and combine this with the first term I get an invalid syntax error

Full interpreter message:
runfile('/home/user_1/p01.py', wdir='/home/user_1')
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/home/user_1/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3291, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)

File "", line 1, in 
    runfile('/home/user_1/p01.py', wdir='/home/user_1')

File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/spyder/utils/site/sitecustomize.py", line 705, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/spyder/utils/site/sitecustomize.py", line 102, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

File "/home/user_1/p01.py", line 91
    dispersion = (sqrt(m-t))
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: You're code seems fine to me. There are no syntax errors here

Comment: How exactly is `formula` used then? (As in, you do realize this is not a function, but a value, right?)

Comment: Please provide the code of the bigger formula and the error you get

Comment: The error I get is invalid syntax

Comment: I have split the code for the bigger formula into smaller sections, I will include the code

Comment: Please provide the **full error message** as produced by the interpreter whe you run the code, it contains information about which point in the code raises it exactly.

Comment: You're missing at least two closing parentheses on the first line of your code. And your error message is related to a  line you're not showing.

Comment: That was just a typo when I copied and pasted it

Answer (score 0):

You can do using list :

```
a = list(numpy_array)
sum([(i-j)**2 for i,j in zip(a,a[1:])])
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
result = sum((ar[i] - ar[i + 1])**2 for i in range(len(ar) - 1))
```

Answer (score 0):

Using numpy:

```
(((a-np.roll(a,1))**2)[1:]).sum()
```

Note: The `[1:]` is necessary because `roll` reinserts the element at the beginning of the array.

Comment: This is an alternative to his own solution, which works fine IMO

Comment: Aren't all alternatives to his solution? He said himself the code works, without detailing what error he gets.

Comment: `it gives an invalid syntax error`, for some reason. Yet I see no syntax errors at all, it seems completely valid

Comment: "but whenever I try to use `formula` in my code..." I start to believe what he actually wants is not the value, but a function that computes said value to plug in a bigger computation. Asked in a comment to the question, let's see..